# MySQL error: Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Tags: mysql

I am Boxonix!

I am currently making a comment section for my website, and I'm tiny a bit in trouble! This "Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'" pops out when i run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY users.id DESC LIMIT $LIMIT1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM comments
JOIN videos ON comments.video_id = videos.id
```

I am already kind a bit confused, I'm not using MySQL that often!
Please help!

Comment: When doing select statements on unions, first of all you need to explicitly state the columns, so that the columns in each query match up, secondly it is good to add COLLATE to the select statements so you aren't getting mixed collations.  for example '(SELECT email COLLATE utf8_general_ci as email FROM users) UNION (SELECT email COLLATE utf8_general_ci  as email FROM subscribers)'

Answer (score 57):

You can force collation in `SELECT` part of query. For example if column `videos.comment` is `utf8_general_ci` and `comments.comment` is `utf8_unicode_ci` you can force it to be same:

```
SELECT 
   comment COLLATE utf8_general_ci
FROM comments
UNION
SELECT 
   comment
FROM videos
```

But this has limited use in case that collations can't be translated exactly as you want.

Comment: This is a good answer! should be accepted as correct! Also you can change on the table's structure the collation type to use the same for all the tables! It's recommended.

Comment: similarly, you should be able to do convert as below in query if needed:
SELECT 
   comment
FROM comments
UNION
SELECT 
   CONVERT(comment USING utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci AS comment
FROM videos

Answer (score 11):

To avoid "*Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'*" MySQL error you must verify that same-index columns have the same type of collation or encoding.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the two sub-queries will have different column sets.

The first sub-query is going to give you all columns from `comments` and all columns from `users`. The second sub-query is going to give you all columns from `comments` and all columns from `videos`. Unless the two tables `users` and `videos` have the exact same column definitions, then the `UNION` is not going to work.

You need to decide what columns you need from each query and then customise each `SELECT ...` so that they match.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error recently. The columns in the `union` must have the same `collations`

Check the `collations` of the columns.

`show full columns from <table_name>;`

and change the collations on the column.

`alter table <table_name> modify <column_name> varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci default null;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use order by statement before union, If you want use first you have to convert the result as temporary table. then say order by condition as below

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM comments
JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM comments
JOIN videos ON comments.video_id = videos.id) as t order by id DESC LIMIT 1
```

the important note here is that both users and videos should have same number of column as comments table..Because if you use `union` or `union all` you should take equal no. of columns with equal data type..

If  comments,users,videos has different number of columns then don't user select * from. instead select all columns explicity as follow

If comments table has columns user_id,col1,col2,col3 then

```
select user_id,col1,col2,col3 from (SELECT c.user_id,col1,col2,col3 FROM 
comments c JOIN users u c.user_id = u.id
UNION
SELECT c.user_id,col1,col2,col3 FROM comments c
JOIN videos v ON c.video_id = v.id) as t 
order by user_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @users3080291 have you try my answer

Comment: @user3080291 all tables you take using union should have same number of columns. may i know the columns of comments,users,videos tables.

Comment: Umm they are not the same... There is way more comments!

Comment: @user3080291 then you can't use union in this situation.  If you want all columns using union query check my updated answer

Comment: @user3080291 check my updated answer and contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$LIMIT1` with `1` and perform `ORDER BY` after second query.Try this:

```
(SELECT *
FROM comments
JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM comments
JOIN videos ON comments.video_id = videos.id)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Note:**The union operation requires that each of your two queries have exactly the same number of columns in their result set.

Comment: Table 'users' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Comment: Still the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

> Simply you have to compare the all the table collation column and it should be same in all the table Like if there is utf8_general_ci then all the tables which you want to merge with union should be having utf8_general_ci or if different then change it from structure or use following query.

```
ALTER TABLE 
`Tablename` 
CHANGE 
`columnname` 
`columnname` VARCHAR(191) 
CHARACTER SET 
utf8 
COLLATE 
utf8_general_ci 
NULL 
DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

For same fields, simply make same collation.