# Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION' Nodejs Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I´m trying to get all the posts that a user wrote using this sql:

```
'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? UNION ALL SELECT * FROM posts WHERE writer_name=?'
```

And i´m getting this error:

```
"Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'"
```

**tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `claudioBlog`.`users` ( 
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
  `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  `age` VARCHAR(100),
  `discription` VARCHAR (255),
  `ocupation` VARCHAR (100),
  `profile_image` VARCHAR (100)
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE (`email`)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB
  
 CREATE TABLE posts (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  category VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  body VARCHAR(2000)  NOT NULL,
  writer_id VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  writer_name VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  post_img VARCHAR(100),
  created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

What do i have to chage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error: Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456152/mysql-error-illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-union)

Answer (score 2):

You want a `join`, not `union`.  Presumably, `writer_id` is a foreign key reference to `users(id)`

```
SELECT p.*
FROM users u JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.writer_id = u.id
WHERE u.username = ? ;
```

Note:  If `write_id` does indeed refer to `users(id)`, it is inappropriate to store `write_name` in `posts`, unless -- for some strange reason -- it can vary by post and is not the users real name.